# Unable to create functions / stored procedure in Azure mySQL

Tags: mysql, azure

I have just set up a mysql database with Azure and I am using Navicat to connect to it and everything is working fine. I am now trying to create some functions and stored procedures, but I am getting a Super User Error:

> You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable) > Time: 0.027s

Here is my code for one of them:

```
CREATE function `triggertradersazure`.`sf_entity_active_sub`(`p_entity_id` INT) 
returns INT(11) 
DETERMINISTIC 
begin 
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
             FROM   tbl_stripe_customer_link_sub sc 
                    JOIN tbl_stripe_sub_payments ss 
                      ON sc.stripe_customer_id = ss.stripe_customer_id 
                         AND ss.stripe_subscription_id = 
                             sc.stripe_subscription_id 
             WHERE  active = 'Y' 
                    AND entity_id = p_entity_id) THEN 
    RETURN 1; 
  ELSE 
    RETURN 0; 
  end IF; 
end;
```

User Info from `mql.user`:

```
INSERT INTO `mysql`.`user` 
            (`host`, `user`, `password`, `select_priv`, `insert_priv`, `update_priv`, `delete_priv`, `create_priv`, `drop_priv`, `reload_priv`, `shutdown_priv`, `process_priv`, `file_priv`, `grant_priv`, `references_priv`, `index_priv`, `alter_priv`, `show_db_priv`, `super_priv`, `create_tmp_table_priv`, `lock_tables_priv`, `execute_priv`, `repl_slave_priv`, `repl_client_priv`, `create_view_priv`, `show_view_priv`, `create_routine_priv`, `alter_routine_priv`, `create_user_priv`, `event_priv`, `trigger_priv`, `create_tablespace_priv`, `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`, `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`, `max_user_connections`, `plugin`, `authentication_string`, `password_expired`) 
VALUES      ('%', 'triggertraders', '*', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'mysql_native_password', '', 'N');
```

This user does not have super user but I should not need it and Azure doesn't allow it?

Not sure what to do with this at the moment. My function had

```
`CREATE DEFINER = `tiggertraders`@`ip`
```

I removed this as this is meant to fix the problem.

Any help would be great,

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to the log_bin_trust_function_creators server properties in Azure to allow this - Show below:

[image]